# By Wolfram $N(n,p)=\Big \lfloor \sqrt p\lfloor n(\sqrt p +p) \rfloor \Big\rfloor$ is even for $p=2$ with some values of $n$, it's always true?

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics

Let n and p be two nonnegative integers and put $N(n,p)=\Big \lfloor \sqrt p\lfloor n(\sqrt p +p) \rfloor \Big\rfloor$.
$N(n,p)$ is not necessarily even when p is even  [[see]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%20Floor%5B%20Sqrt%5B10%5D%20Floor%5B71%5BSqrt%5B10%5D%20%2B%2010%5D%5D%5D%3B%20)
But  it's seems  that $N(n,2)$ is even forall n. It's true ?

Comment: ? $N(2,2)=8$ which is even, so what do you mean when you write "it seems that $N(n,2)$ is odd for all $n$"?

Comment: I corrected the typo thank you

Comment: Please avoid creation of new tags. Existing tags already cover your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $k<n\sqrt{2}<k+1$ for integer $k$, and $n\sqrt{2}=k+\delta$. Then $\lfloor n(\sqrt{2}+2)\rfloor=k+2n$ and $\sqrt{2}\lfloor n(\sqrt{2}+2)\rfloor=\sqrt{2}(k+2n)=2n-\sqrt{2}\delta+2(k+\delta)=2(n+k)+\delta(2-\sqrt{2})$, thus $$\lfloor \sqrt{2}\lfloor n(\sqrt{2}+2)\rfloor\rfloor=2(n+k).$$

Comment: Thank you so much